# JSP Database setTime, get a time from form

Tags: database, jsp

```
// Create the prepared statement and use it to
// INSERT the student attributes INTO the Student table.
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
"INSERT INTO Review VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("section_id")));
pstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("quarter"));                   
pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year")));
pstmt.setTime(4, ????)
```

Can anyone tell me how can i read values with the type Time?? Lets say time like "16:34"? How can I define a pattern and read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this.

```
  public static java.sql.Time getCurrentJavaSqlTime(String time) {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);  //Convert to Date
    return new java.sql.Time(date.getTime());  //Now to time
  }

  java.sql.Time time = getCurrentJavaSqlTime("16:34");
  System.out.println("time=" + time);
  pstmt.setTime(4,time);
```

Use format patterns to work with yout String.

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)   Number             0
k   Hour in day (1-24)   Number             24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11) Number             0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12) Number             12
m   Minute in hour       Number             30
```

To obtain from user try this

```
java.sql.Time time = getCurrentJavaSqlTime((String)request.getParameter("time"));
 pstmt.setTime(4,time);
```

Comment: Thx a lot!! But how can i read that from an input of the form?

Comment: 16:34 is input by user, not the current time

Comment: Just copy getCurrentJavaSqlTime method it will do the work, the pattern is already defined, how you force the user to do that is another story.

Comment: Do I have to add some headers?

Comment: Add java.util.Locale to your import section

Comment: Why it says Unparseable date: "time" in my browser when I try to insert??

Comment: Thx a lot!!! it works!! But a problem that it displays"11:33:00" instead of "11:33" i input. Any solutions? And whats that Locale.English for?

Comment: Yes, because it is a time and it should have seconds  . Dont forget to accept my answer =)

Comment: Of course! So there is no way to just have hours and mins??

Comment: In your database I think not, but when you print to the screen you can remove the seconds with String methods

Comment: So how can I modify this? <td>
                                <input value="<%= rs.getString("time") %>" 
                                    name="time" size="5">
                            </td>

Comment: <%= rs.getString("time").substring(0,4) %>

Comment: Holy crap buddy you are so good!! Is there anyway else I can do except for accept your answer to give your points or sth?? Im kinda new here. its such a great place!

Comment: Give a up vote in the arrows left to my question, accepted is ok, thanks. And welcome